# Display data fields based on checkbox selection in SAP ABAP

Tags: abap

Below is simple code where I want to display location based on checkbox selection.

Eg: id p_pune is selected at seletion screen then after WRITE command my output should be as below

```
EMPID  NAME  LOCATION
 1       A     PUNE
```

Code:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_emp,
       empid TYPE i,
       name TYPE char5,
       location TYPE char6,
  END OF ty_emp.

  DATA: wa_emp TYPE ty_emp,
        it_emp TYPE TABLE OF ty_emp.

  DATA: gd_ucomm TYPE sy-ucomm.

  wa_emp-empid = 1.
  wa_emp-name = 'A'.
  wa_emp-location = 'Pune'.
  append wa_emp to  it_emp.

CLEAR wa_emp.
   wa_emp-empid = 2.
  wa_emp-name = 'B'.
  wa_emp-location = 'Mumbai'.
append wa_emp to  it_emp.

CLEAR wa_emp.
  wa_emp-empid = 3.
  wa_emp-name = 'C'.
  wa_emp-location = 'Delhi'.
append wa_emp to  it_emp.

CLEAR wa_emp.
  wa_emp-empid = 4.
  wa_emp-name = 'D'.
  wa_emp-location = 'Noida'.
  append wa_emp to  it_emp.

CLEAR wa_emp.

PARAMETERS: p_pune AS CHECKBOX USER-COMMAND c1,
            p_mumbai AS CHECKBOX USER-COMMAND c2,
            p_delhi AS CHECKBOX USER-COMMAND c3,
            p_noida AS CHECKBOX USER-COMMAND c4.
```

Comment: It's not clear what issue you have. Is it about how to use `IF`, how to use the debugger, etc. ? Please show what you tried, and ask a question about a precise problem. Have a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how to ask questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
IF p_pune = abap_true.

  READ TABLE it_emp INTO wa_emp INDEX '1'.

  WRITE:/ wa_emp-empid, wa_emp-name, wa_emp-location.

ENDIF.

IF p_mumbai = abap_true.

  READ TABLE it_emp INTO wa_emp INDEX '2'.

  WRITE:/ wa_emp-empid, wa_emp-name, wa_emp-location.

ENDIF.

IF p_delhi = abap_true.

  READ TABLE it_emp INTO wa_emp INDEX '3'.

  WRITE:/ wa_emp-empid, wa_emp-name, wa_emp-location.

ENDIF.

IF p_noida = abap_true.

  READ TABLE it_emp INTO wa_emp INDEX '4'.

  WRITE:/ wa_emp-empid, wa_emp-name, wa_emp-location.

ENDIF.
```

When you check multiple checkboxes, it will display multiple locations.

If you want to display only one location, I suggest you use RADIO BUTTON instead of CHECKBOX.

Comment: Will it work for more then 2 records of same location? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did not quite understand your question. You want to display multiple locations for the same checkbox , or multiple checkboxes to display the same location? For both questions the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the boolean values of the parameters to a location, using the `COND` statement. Then you can loop over the internal table with `LOOP AT` and use it's `WHERE` condition to filter out the location you need.

```
TYPES:
  BEGIN OF employee,
    empid    TYPE i,
    name     TYPE char5,
    location TYPE char6,
  END OF employee,
  employees TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF employee WITH EMPTY KEY.

DATA(employees) = VALUE employees(
  ( empid = 1 name = 'A' location = 'Pune'   )
  ( empid = 2 name = 'B' location = 'Mumbai' )
  ( empid = 3 name = 'C' location = 'Dehli'  )
  ( empid = 4 name = 'D' location = 'Noida'  )
).

PARAMETERS: pune   AS CHECKBOX,
            mumbai AS CHECKBOX,
            dehli  AS CHECKBOX,
            noida  AS CHECKBOX.

START-OF-SELECTION.

DATA(wanted_location) = COND char6(
  WHEN pune   = abap_true THEN 'Pune'
  WHEN mumbai = abap_true THEN 'Mumbai'
  WHEN dehli  = abap_true THEN 'Dehli'
  WHEN noida  = abap_true THEN 'Noida'
).

LOOP AT employees INTO DATA(employee)
  WHERE location = wanted_location.

  WRITE:
    employee-empid,
    employee-location,
    employee-name.

  NEW-LINE.
ENDLOOP.
```